# Call stored procedure returned Multiple cursors by using LINQ C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, oracle, linq

I need your kind help as I have a stored procedure which returns more than one cursor in pl/sql and I want to call it from ASP.NET and C# using linq. Can I do that and get the value returned from each cursor with a single call of the procedure?

Comment: I don't think that a stored procedure returned more than one cursor -- cursors don't exist in C#  Do you mean more than one table?

Comment: i have procedure in pl/sql like the below:
PROCEDURE GET_DATA(_CHANNEL         IN VARCHAR2,
                                            O_CONF_ID_TYPE_CUR        OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                             O_REASONS_CUR OUT SYS_REFCURSOR,
                                                       O_ERRCODE                 OUT VARCHAR2,
                                                       O_ERRDESC                 OUT VARCHAR2);

and O_CONF_ID_TYPE_CUR , O_REASONS_CUR are cursors and need to call this procedure from c# using linq